# Error GlobalExceptionHandler, Error 401 doesn't show error details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I recently implemented authentication in my API Rest, but when the user tries to access to api without being auntenticatedn the exception message doesn't appear:
This is my GlobalExceptionHandler with the method exception that cover all errors in the api:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handlerExceptionMethod(Exception ex , WebRequest 
          webRequest){

          ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), 
          webRequest.getDescription(false));

          return new ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails>(errorDetails, 
          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

}
```

The Postman sofware returns an 1, I want to see the errorDetails parameters. This is my ErrorDetails class:

```
@Getter
public class ErrorDetails {

private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;

public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
}


}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this ControllerAdvice to be triggered?  Spring has a built-in filter for catching AuthenticationExceptions.  In my opinion, you should not try to override this behavior, especially if you're plan is the return a status code of 500 instead of 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by addding the following line of code in Security COnfig class:

```
.antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
```